# Are <meta HTTP-EQUIV> cache settings supported by any modern browsers?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, http, webkit, mozilla

Yes, I know headers are better.  But we've all dealt with *that* system where we want something to be cached (HTML only in this case as it's a tag) like so:

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=200" />

It does not appear to work when I test it casually.  Is there any way to get a document to be cached for, say, 200 seconds without access to an .htaccess file or a programming language?

I know it's not ideal, but it's occasionally functional.  I was hoping there would be a way to denote a particular directory with some sort of simple rules in the HTML cache manifest.  No dice.

Answer (score 0):

IE has partial (and buggy) support for using a `META` tag to *prevent* caching, but this doesn't allow you to specify a non-zero freshness lifetime.

Specifying the freshness lifetime using the `Cache-Control` response header is absolutely the right way to go.

Comment: I'd do if I could.  The problem is the vast majority of CMSes I deal with don't give control over headers.  It's really a common problem.  I wish browsers took it more seriously.

Comment: This isn't a browser problem, it's a CMS problem.

Comment: Respectfully, you know as well as I know that there are tons of SaaS products that won't realize there's a problem.

Comment: Whether that's true or not isn't very relevant. The problem with saying "Browsers should fix this by supporting META in HTML" is that it does nothing for where the majority of byte-weight comes from (images, fonts, script, css, audio, video).

Comment: It's limited, yes, but one can move many of those resources to an CDN. I've done that for some. There were actually some web servers that parsed it out _from_ the meta tags. Probably a bad idea, but I know at least one did.